# IPW-adjusted Kaplan-Meier analysis and IPW-adjusted RMST analysis after multiple imputation

Tags: r, r-mice, gtsummary

I would like to do the following analyses with the dataset with missing variables. Because `mice` and `MatchThem` packages do not support pooling the results of Kaplan-Meier analysis, I try to do it manually as follows:

1. Do multiple imputations using `mice`.
2. Calculate inverse probability weights in each imputed dataset using `WeightIt`.
3. Estimate IPW-adjusted Kaplan-Meier curves in each imputed dataset using `survfit`.
4. Pool the results of #3 and depict the pooled IPW-adjusted KM curves.
5. Calculate the difference in IPW-adjusted restricted mean survival time (the area under KM curve until the specific timepoint) according to `akm-rmst` (https://github.com/s-conner/akm-rmst) within each imputed dataset.
6. Pool the results of #5.
7. Get descriptive statistics of baseline characteristics in imputed dataset using `tbl_summary` from `gtsummary` package.

Here are my codes

```
pacman::p_load(survival, survey, survminer, WeightIt, tidyverse, mice)

df # sample dataset

m <- 10 # number of imputation

dimp <- mice::mice(df, m = m, seed = 123)

for (i in 1:m) {
  dcomp <- mice::complete(dimp, i) # extract imputed data
  
  # estimate weight
  wgt <- weightit(
    treatment ~ age + sex + smoking, 
    data = dcomp, method = "ps", estimand = "ATE", stabilize = TRUE
  )

  # add weight and pscore to dataset
  dimp <- tibble(dcomp, wgt = wgt[["weights"]], pscores = wgt[["ps"]]) 

  assign(paste0("df", i), output) # save "i"th imputed dataset

  # calculate Kaplan-Meier estimate
  surv <- survival::survfit(Surv(time, event) ~ treatment, data = dimp, weight = wgt)

  assign(paste0("surv", i), output) # save "i"th IPW-adjusted KM curves
}
```

These codes do the analyses from #1 to #3. Although I read the reference (https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-pooling.html), I could not find how to do these analyses(#4 to #7). Can anyone give me some advice regarding #4 to #7?

I believe this is not a duplicate to any posted question so I'd appreciate any advice. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, the gtsummary package does not support imputed data objects for `tbl_summary()`. FYI

Comment: I really appreciate your response and your managing gtsummary.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `adjustedCurves` package directly to do all of these calculations. It directly supports IPTW Kaplan-Meier curves, multiple imputation and the subsequent calculation of differences in restricted mean survival time. Here is a small example using simulated data:

```
library(adjustedCurves)
library(mice)
library(WeightIt)

set.seed(42)

# simulate some data as example
sim_dat <- sim_confounded_surv(n=50, max_t=1.2)
sim_dat$group <- as.factor(sim_dat$group)

# introduce random missingness in x1 as example
# NOTE: This is only done as an example, in reality you would
#       already have missing data, not introduce it yourself.
sim_dat$x1 <- ifelse(runif(n=50) < 0.5, sim_dat$x1, NA)

# perform multiple imputation
mids <- mice::mice(data=sim_dat, method="pmm", m=2, printFlag=FALSE)

# IPTW KM using WeightIt on each imputed dataset
adj <- adjustedsurv(data=mids,
                    variable="group",
                    ev_time="time",
                    event="event",
                    method="iptw_km",
                    treatment_model=group ~ x1 + x2 + x5 + x6,
                    weight_method="ps",
                    conf_int=TRUE)

# plotting the pooled resulting curve
plot(adj, conf_int=TRUE)

# get adjusted restricted mean survival times
adjusted_rmst(adj, to=0.6)

# or directly show the difference in adjusted rmst
adjusted_rmst(adj, to=0.6, difference=TRUE)
```

If you additionally want to calculate the confidence interval of the difference in adjusted restricted mean survival time or a p-value testing whether this difference is statistically significant from 0, you could set `bootstrap=TRUE` in the `adjustedsurv()` function call. This would take a while to compute though.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your point #7. When you look for imputation with presumably the need of a high number of datasets (m=20, 40 or > 50) you cannot pick only one dataset in random. Risk of type-one error and you lose the effect of your imputation. Had the same concerns like you. this thread could help you (only for a summary of imputed descriptive data) : [Björn answer in StackExchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/417791/how-to-select-the-best-dataset-after-multiple-imputation-in-mice-to-build-other)